# Excel Services User Defined Function returns #NAME?

Tags: excel-services, com

I've followed all the steps as described in numerous blog posts, including the [MSDN Walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms572961(office.14).aspx), on setting up User Defined Functions in Excel Services.  However, I'm still getting "#NAME?" in the function fields.

Is there additional configuration that needs to be done?  Do I need to use REGASM to register a COM object for it to work?  If so, doesn't that mean it'll need to be registered on all client machines?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was targeting the wrong framework.  It was using 4.0, not 3.5.  Found this in the logs after an IISReset.